# Get South Africa Standard Time In Php

Tags: php

this function is used to get current time of my system, I want to get South Africa time, so plz guide me.

```
$today = time () ;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

Comment: You should at least restore the timezone afterwards. See date_default_timezone_get

Comment: Thought about that too, but the question made me unsure .. maybe the South Africa time is desired across the whole site .. anyway, good point, up to @aamir

Comment: You may want to add this link to your answer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php

Answer (score 5):

```
$d = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg"));
echo $d->format("r");
```

gives

```
Mon, 07 Jun 2010 02:02:12 +0200
```

You can change the format. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`time()` gives the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT (excluding leap seconds), so it doesn't depend on the timezone.

EDIT: For a countdown, you can do:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg");
$now = new DateTime("now", $tz);
$start = new DateTime("2010-06-11 16:00:00", $tz);
$diff = $start->diff($now);
echo "Days: " . $diff->format("%d") . "\n";
echo "Hours: " . $diff->format("%h") . "\n";
echo "Minutes: " . $diff->format("%i") . "\n";
echo "Seconds: " . $diff->format("%s") . "\n";
```

Comment: me using it in a count down timer...
its code:
$date = explode(" ",$row['Date']);
//print $date[0].'>>';
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date[0]);
list($h, $min, $sec) = explode(':', $date[1]);

$target = mktime($h, $min, $sec, $m, $d, $y) ;
$today = time () ;

$difference =($target-$today) ;
  if ($difference < 0) $difference = 0;

$days_left = floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60)/60);
Now guide me how cane me put this code.

Comment: is it possible ime can get the Number of Seconnds Since January 1 1970 00:00:00: (including leap year ) it will depend on timezone

Answer (score 1):

The [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function returns the same value all around the world. Its return value is not dependent on the local time zone.

To convert a time value to your local time, call the [`localtime()`](http://php.net/localtime) function.